# How to write a selectionSort method going in Descending order?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, methods

**Hello there! At the moment, I am just a tad bit confused with my code. I'd like to move my array in descending order. This sounds very simple but for some reason I cannot wrap my head around this method. Currently, this is a selectionSort method I wrote that goes directly in ascending order. I'm not sure where to start when it comes to descending order.. as to how to reverse the equations, I usually end up overflowing since it's supposed to be using the original ".length" of the array.**

Thank you very much for any help!

```
int[] arr = {5, 3, 2, 44, 1, 75, 23, 15};

private static void descendingSort (int[] arr) {

        for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            int smallestIndex = i;

            for ( int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                //searching for smallest...
                //if statement declaring if arr is smaller than the index[0] 
                if (arr[j] < arr[smallestIndex]) { 
                    //now it has changed to pickle because it has swapped. thx u 
                    smallestIndex = j;
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `if (arr[j] < arr[smallestIndex])` to `if (arr[j] > arr[smallestIndex])` ? I'm rather confused how you end up overflowing or what kind of changes you make that no longer use `.length`

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! It's like learning an entirely new language so it is quite hard to direct it into english, hehe. Yes, actually! Here is my new code: (I am new to SO it appears my code is too long.. one moment lol 

Comment: @UnholySheep I've tried to change the if statement to various less than or equal to things, just making arr[j] less than arr[smallestIndex] but gosh nothing changes! :( 

```for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
   
   int smallestIndex = i;

   for ( int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[j] >= arr[smallestIndex]) { 

     smallestIndex = j;
     
           int temp = arr[smallestIndex];
           arr[smallestIndex] = arr[i];
           arr[smallestIndex] = temp;
    }```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the non-working example, it is unreadable if you stuff it into a comment like this

Comment: @UnholySheep Sorry D: will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to solve the problem fast, here's how you approach it.
Notice we just change a few lines.

Specifically ...

1. We still find the smallest element
2. We put it in the back and not the front
3. The iteration order in both loops is `back-to-front` and not `front-to-back`

An easier way to implement this would be to just sort the elements in ascending order and then just reverse the array.

```
 void selectionSortDescending(int arr[])
    {
        int n = arr.length;

        // Start by finding the smallest element to put in the very back
        // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray
        for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
            int min_idx = i;
            for (int j = i-1; j >= 0; j--)
                if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
                    min_idx = j;
 
            // Swap the found minimum element with the last element
            int temp = arr[min_idx];
            arr[min_idx] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow!!!! Yes this is exactly it! I can't thank you and Sheep enough for your quick responses, I really appreciate it!  One reason I seemed to have an issue with was pushing the smallest element back before beginning anything else. Eespecially with that i-1, I think that is where I hit an overflow error. THANK YOU!

Comment: Any time, bro ;)

Comment: YOU DA MAN :)))

Comment: Ahahaha ... I am delighted to hear this.